# How to .Activate Word document from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working on an Excel workbook that has many userforms, and a user guide.

On the userforms a "Help" button opens the user guide to the relevant section for the userform where the button was pressed.

I cannot get the Word document to consistently be the active window once the button is pressed.

```vb
Dim path As String
Dim userGuide As Word.Document
Dim wordApp As Word.Application

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\User Guide.doc"

If Len(Dir(path)) > 0 Then
    
    'Set userGuide to be already opened User Guide
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set userGuide = wordApp.Documents("User Guide.doc")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'If userGuide is nothing, then User Guide is not already open
    If userGuide Is Nothing Then
    
        'Open User Guide
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wordApp.Visible = True
        Set userGuide = wordApp.Documents.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\User Guide.doc")

    End If
    
    wordApp.Activate
    
Else
    MsgBox "User Guide could not be found."

End If
```

The Word document opens, but the `wordApp.Activate` line works intermittently. It seems to work once I have opened the VBA module which holds this code, but until I have done that the Word document opens in the background and the user has to manually switch windows. This makes me think this is more of an Excel "feature" rather than a bug in my code.

I tried `DoEvents` both before and after `wordApp.Activate`, but that made no difference.

Note that my Excel file is a .xls file (as in Excel 97-2003 Workbook). Saving it as .xlsm causes another Excel "feature" to pop up, and changing the extension is the quick fix I have found for that.

Comment: The code that I has posted below(now deleted) was tried and tested. It worked for me. When you ran that code, what exactly happened?

Comment: The same as my code above. It opened the word document in the background, but did not activate the word application, so the user would have to manually switch from excel to word. This is only an intermittent problem for me though, it works once I've opened the module where the code is stored, but the VBA will be password protected when the final version is shared and so that will not be an option for the end user.

Comment: This happens. I'm not sure whether anyone has ever figured out exactly why... You'll probably need to use the Windows API to get more reliable results.